# Basic Anagram VS more advanced one

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm currently working my way through a "List" unit and in one of the exercises we need to create an anagram (for those who don't know; *two words are an anagram if you can rearrange the letters from one to spell the other*).

The easier solution that comes to mind is:

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)

print is_anagram('god', 'dog')
```

It works, but it doesn't really satisfy me. If we were in this situation for example:

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)

print is_anagram('god', 'dyog') #extra letter 'd' in second argument
>>> False
```

Return is False, although we should be able to to build the word `'god'` out of `'dyog'`. Perhaps this game/problem isn't called an anagram, but I've been trying to figure it out anyway.

**Technically my solution is to:**
1- Iterate through every element of b.
2- As I do, I check if that element exists in a.
3- If all of them do; then we can create a out of b.
4- Otherwise, we can't.

I just can't seem to get it to work. **For the record, I do not know how to use `lambda`**

**Some tests:**

```
print is_anagram('god', 'ddog') #should return True
print is_anagram('god', '9d8s0og') #should return True
print is_anagram('god', '_@10d_o g') #should return True
```

Thanks :)

Comment: So you need to check if `a` string could be made from `b`?

Comment: Does it need to work in both directions? For example, should `is_anagram('dyog', 'god')` return `True`, like the opposite does? Or is the order necessary? It's not much of a change, but the answers I see below don't do that.

Comment: @vishes_shell yes sir.

Comment: @DavidHeyman, any order and any situation.

Comment: Incidentally, `lambda` is fairly simple - `lambda x: x in a` is the same as `def foo(x): return x in a`, except without giving it any actual name, so you have to pass it as an argument or assign it to a variable. There can be any number of arguments, but the body has to be a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if `a` word could be created from `b` you can do this

```
def is_anagram(a,b):
    b_list = list(b)
    for i_a in a:
        if i_a in b_list:
            b_list.remove(i_a)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

**UPDATE(Explanation)**

`b_list = list(b)` makes a `list` of `str` objects(characters).

```
>>> b = 'asdfqwer'
>>> b_list = list(b)
>>> b_list
['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r']
```

What basically is happening in the answer: We check if every character in `a` listed in `b_list`, when occurrence happens we remove that character from `b_list`(we do that to eliminate possibility of returning `True` with input `'good'`, `'god'`). So if there is no occurrence of another character of `a` in rest of `b_list` then it's not advanced anagram.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre fixed that.

Comment: @vishes_shell, thank you for that. I'll explore it and study it, but it did pass all the tests :) Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Vayl glad that it helped.

Comment: This works very well! Just a question, why did you use `b_list = list(b)` - what changed here?

Comment: @Vayl i've updated answer with explanation, if you have any question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers do not, at time of writing, support reversing the order:

Contains [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for convenience, because why not?

```
# Just strip hints out if you're in Python < 3.5.
def is_anagram(a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    long, short = (a, b) if len(a) > len(b) else (b, a)
    cut = [x for x in long if x in short]
    return sorted(cut) == sorted(short)
```

If, in future, you do learn to use `lambda`, an equivalent is:

```
# Again, strip hints out if you're in Python < 3.5.
def is_anagram(a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    long, short = (a, b) if len(a) > len(b) else (b, a)
    # Parentheses around lambda are not necessary, but may help readability
    cut = filter((lambda x: x in short), long)
    return sorted(cut) == sorted(short)
```

Comment: David, I will go over both this answer and your comment above tomorrow morning with a fresh mind. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: `is_anagram('god', 'ddog')` should return `True`

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    word = [filter(lambda x: x in a, sub) for sub in b]
    return ''.join(word)[0:len(a)]
```

Example:

```
>>> is_anagram('some','somexcv')
'some'
```

**Note:** This code returns the `common word` if there is any or `''` otherwise. (it doesn't return `True/False` as the OP asked - realized that after, but anyway this code can easily change to adapt the `True/False` type of result - I won't fix it now such there are great answers in this post that already do :) )

> Brief explanation:

This code takes(`filter`) every letter(`sub`) on `b` word that exists in `a` word also. Finally returns the word which must have the same length as a(`[0:len(a)]`). The last part with `len` needs for cases like this:
`is_anagram('some','somenothing')`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm afraid I can't really understand it. Never used `lambda` and your code is too tight for me :)

Comment: @Vayl, I meant to help, and I really would like to explain the code, but since you've never used lambda before - I couldn't do that in a single post... anyway thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: I appreciate it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    test = sorted(a) == sorted(b)
    testset = b in a
    testset1 = a in b
    if testset == True:
        return True
    if testset1 == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

No better than the other solution. But if you like verbose code, here's mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think all this sorting is a red herring; the letters should be counted instead.

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    return all(a.count(c) <= b.count(c) for c in set(a))
```

If you want efficiency, you can construct a dictionary that counts all the letters in `b` and decrements these counts for each letter in `a`. If any count is below 0, there are not enough instances of the character in `b` to create `a`. This is an `O(a + b)` algorithm.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def is_anagram(a, b):
    b_dict = defaultdict(int)

    for char in b:
        b_dict[char] += 1

    for char in a:
        b_dict[char] -= 1
        if b_dict[char] < 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Iterating over `b` is inevitable since you need to count all the letters there. This will exit as soon as a character in `a` is not found, so I don't think you can improve this algorithm much.